# React how to bind to component when calling onSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my component, I'm trying to call in an handleChange and handleSubmit functions of a component

If I render like the [forms example](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html),

```
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter new title"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

in onChange(), `this` won't be bound to the component, and I can't call `this.setState`, so I bind it with onChange={() => this.handleChange}.

for `onSubmit()`, I have the same binding problem, but when I bind it, the handler is not called, and the page is reloaded.  What is the right way to bind to the component when submitting?

TIA

Full example:

```
class CbList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      newTitle: '',
      list: []
    };
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState(Object.assign({},
                                this.state,
                                { newTitle: event.target.value }));
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.addBlock(this.state.newTitle);
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="cb-list">
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={() => this.handleChange}
                   placeholder="Enter new title"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  addBlock(title) {
    let updatedList = this.state.list.concat({ title: title });
    this.setState({ list: updatedList })
  }
};

$(function() {
  ReactDOM.render(<CbList/>, $('#home').get(0));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `bind` you event handlers on constructor so you can use them among other events.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
}
```

Also, you don't need arrow function when using then as props.

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <input
    type="text"
    value={this.state.value}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    placeholder="Enter new title"
  />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  Can't figure out why I had to do this, but in the tutorial, forms didn't need that...

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to invoke the functions:

```
onSubmit={()=>this.handleSubmit}
```

should be

```
onSubmit={()=>this.handleSubmit()}
```

Or, just pass a reference to the function:

```
onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
```

but you'll need to bind your functions in the constructor (as show in the forms example link):

```
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
```

Comment: Instead of this, we can also define as `const submitHabdler = () => {...}`. This way we can use it more than 1 time

Comment: `onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit()}` invokes the function, but the `event` is `null`.  

And, `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}` fails as above (this is not bound).

Comment: Of course! Either invoke the function, or bind it without wrapping it - I'd prefer binding it as it saves a redundant function call, but passes arguments from the event. I highly recommend [exploring es6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/index.html) which is a wonderful and free book about ES6. (He has additional free, online book about javascript [here](http://exploringjs.com/))